# add a path to a phtml file -- customise url

Tags: module, url, phtml, ee-1.14

Anyone know how i can customise the path for a module so i can have a few paths elements?

I have a module. in the modules xml i have something like

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <mycustomerrouter>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>my_module_name</module>
                <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
            </args>
        </mycustomerrouter>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

I can navigate fine to `www.myurl.com/mymodule`
but how can i make it so i can customise my url in the format of
`http://www.myurl.com/some/path/here/mymodule`.

Changing the frontname doesnt seem to work eg `<frontName>some/path/here/mymodule</frontName>` does not work.

Comment: you are manage via URL Rewrite Management in admin side

Answer (score 0):

you can try create sub directories in you module and create controller

```
 - controllers
   -- Some
   ---Path
   ----Here
   -----MymoduleController
```

and set route as `some` but best set this route uniquer for your module. for example, `mymodule/some/path/here` and you can get this path in you `someController` and get parameter `path` for render information...